# How to tell if a plot is complete or not

Tags: r, graphics, knitr

Update: I asked Paul Murrell (the "final boss"), and he told me the decision of opening a new page is made in `src/library/graphics/src/graphics.c` by `GNewPlot`:

```
pGEDevDesc GNewPlot(Rboolean recording)
```

Effectively it looks at `par(mfg)` and `par(new)` to decide whether to open a new page. How do I that test in an add-on package?

A solution using either pure [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) code or some C code is acceptable.

---

`knitr` uses the `evaluate` package to evaluate R code chunks, and capture results, including plots. Briefly speaking, `evaluate` calls `recordPlot()` to record a snapshot of the current plot after each code expression has been evaluated, and also when the plotting hooks like `before.plot.new` and `before.grid.newpage` are called (normally this happens before a new plot is drawn). For those "Luke's", please [use the source](https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/blob/master/R/graphics.r) if this is not clear enough.

After we make a snapshot, we need to decide whether to keep it, because the snapshot might not be changed after we evaluate a new expression, which is not involved with plotting. Now here comes my problem: when a plot contains sub-plots (for example, `pairs()`, `coplot()`, or `par(mfrow = c(2, 3))` in base R graphics), we should not keep the incomplete snapshots. In the example below, the first three plots should be discarded:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(rnorm(10))
plot(rnorm(10))
plot(rnorm(10))
plot(rnorm(10))
```

To achieve this, we compare `par("mfg")[1:2]` to `par("mfg")[3:4]` (as you can see in the source code), and this works well in some cases, but not all, for example, the [issue #25](https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/issues/25):

```
layout(matrix(c(1,3,2,3), 2))
plot(rnorm(10))
plot(rnorm(10))
plot(rnorm(10))
```

Now how do I know the plot is not complete before line 4? The `mfg` trick no longer works.

I have been looking for an answer to this problem for a long time, and I will truly appreciate it if someone can give me a hint; further details are in the two links above, and I can clarify if anything is unclear. I believe there must exist a solution, because all R devices know when to start a new plot screen or file, and incomplete plots will not trigger new plot screens or files.

Comment: I really think there's no way to identify if the plot is complete and there won't be later an R expression that would extend that further. What I did in [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander) with the `evals` function (that I use instead of `evaluate` for some extra), is that the user can "mark" a line with a leading `+` sign to be included in that last called plot -- that is a really unoptimal solution, but I could not come up with any better idea. Further details: http://support.rapporter.net/entries/22485898-How-to-evaluate-multiple-commands-together

Comment: defining a layout doesn't necessarily mean that all cells will actually be used in the end, does it? I can imagine situations where one cell is left blank on purpose. There wouldn't be a need for `dev.off()` if there was a definite answer, I reckon.

Comment: @daroczig thanks! I think that is indeed suboptimal; @baptiste you are right; one can `dev.off()` before all cells are filled up, and that is not a concern for me

Comment: Hi everyone, there is no need to look into this question any more. I have got the official support from R core. I'll post the answer once it is finalized.

Comment: That's great news. Really looking forward to seeing how you solve this and gain access to the relevant lower-level C functions.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I have posted the answer below.

Comment: So it looks like the way to access the relevant C functions is "Paul Murrell" ;)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien absolutely! I was drowned there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: this is available in R 3.0.2 now.

---

In his [recent commit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/aea9a24fa85), Paul Murrell added a new read-only parameter in `par()` named `page`, which gives `TRUE` or `FALSE`, indicating whether the next plot needs to open a new page.

This was achieved by copying some code from `GNewPlot()`, and is only available in R-devel at the moment.

Comment: This is now available in R 3.0.2

Answer (score 4):

From `?par`:

> ```
>  ‘mfg’ A numerical vector of the form ‘c(i, j)’ where ‘i’ and ‘j’
>       indicate which figure in an array of figures is to be drawn
>       next (if setting) or is being drawn (if enquiring).  The
>       array must already have been set by ‘mfcol’ or ‘mfrow’.
> ```

So, it seems that you'd need to use a [pairing function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PairingFunction.html) to assign a unique id to the initial value of `par("mfg")[1:2]`, and then test subsequent values of `par("mfg")[1:2]` against that key.  A valid paring, for example, would be `2**par("mfg")[1] * 3**par("mfg")[2]`:

```
Pid <- function(ij, test.id=NA){
        mi <- ij[1]
        mj <- ij[2]
        ijd <- 2**mi * 3**mj
        if (!is.na(test.id)) ijd <- ijd == test.id
        return(ijd)
}
```

Back to your example:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,3,2,3), 2))
x0 <- par("mfg")  # 2 1 2 2
id <- Pid(x0)     # 12
plot(rnorm(10))
x1 <- par("mfg")
p1 <- Pid(x1, id) # FALSE (layout is not full)
plot(rnorm(10))
x2 <- par("mfg")
p2 <- Pid(x2, id) # FALSE (layout is not full)
plot(rnorm(10))
x3 <- par("mfg")
p3 <- Pid(x3, id) # TRUE (layout is now full)
#
rbind(p1,p2,p3)
#    [,1]
#p1 FALSE
#p2 FALSE
#p3  TRUE
```

I suppose, however, that without the initial `id`, you'd be out of luck.

Comment: thanks! you have given me a good inspiration! the pairing function is not critical here; it is the initial `mfg` that is really important; I can simply use `identical()` to compare subsequent `mfg` values to the initial vector, and I [have done that](https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/commit/5f1ca6b5e9b19fc734e0792d9a65334637b3a013), but I still do not think it is a reliable approach